# How to Load csv File into MySQL from Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to load `csv` files into MySQL using Python.

I am getting error while inserting values.

I dropped the header row

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("insert into products(pr_id,pr_name,pr_category) values(%%s,%%s,%%s)",row) 
    print(df)
```

Programming error:

> not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Comment: What CSV module are you using? The normal ```csv```? What MySQL connector are you using? Is it ```mysql.connector```? I'm asking because their uses may differ from alternatives. For example the parameter syntax for queries with ```mysql.connector.execute``` specifies ```%s``` as placeholder, not ```%%s```. Similarly from the code above I can't tell what data type/structure ```row``` is, neither ```df```.

Comment: i just created excel file with products with features like pr_id,pr_name,pr_category for practicing purpose.i deleted header row..but getting same error.i used mysqldb for connecting purpose.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the complete code and an excerpt of the data? The error message suggests that there are more than three entries in ```row``` or maybe one of the entries is of a type that cannot be converted. It's hard to tell what ```row``` is from just the given code and data.